In Unity, how to make World Space XR UI Canvas Scale with the Child Input Field TMP?
I have an XR UI canvas that is set to World Space.
It has a child object which is an Input Field.
If the text input overflows the Input field, I have made it to expand vertically downwards using a 'content size fitter'.
But the issue is, when the input field expands, the parent canvas doesnt expand with it.
I want the parent canvas to expand too.
Since at a point, the input field expands beyond the canvas and it looks ugly when it does so. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?


I am using Unity 2022.3.23f1 to create an XR app using OpenXR for the Oculus Quest 3 and was playing with the spatial keyboard sample scene provided by XRI toolkit 3.0.4.

I figured it out.
Its because of all the Vertical/Horizontal Layout elements in each game object.
Once I disabled them all and made the RectTransform of each object set to stretch on all sides, I was able to achieve what I set my mind on.
